# Which DISKPART volume do I select for MBR fix?

Tags: windows, mbr, diskpart

- My Windows 10 system crashed on insertion of the power supply cable and now has alternating MBR and registry erros on reboot. I'm trying to fix the MBR on my 920 GB NVMe M.2 SSD.
- I've booted with Windows USB and got a command window running.
- I'm running DISKPART and get the following information:

---

```
DISKPART> list vol

 Volume ###  Ltr  Label          Fs      Type          Size     Status     Info
 ----------  ---  -------------  ------  ------------  -------  ---------  --------
 Volume 0         Windows RE     NTFS    Partition      300 MB  Healthy   
 Volume 1     C   OSDisk         NTFS    Partition      893 GB  Healthy  
 Volume 2                        FAT32   Partition      512 MB  Healthy    Hidden
 Volume 3     E                          Removable        0 MB  No Media
 Volume 4     D   ESD-USB        FAT32   Removable       14 GB  Healthy
```

---

Volume 1 is my C: drive. Volume 4 is the USB drive being used to boot the machine.

The next steps will be

```
sel vol n           (where n is one of the volumes above)
assign letter=x:
```

My question is which number to select for vol n?

---

I'm following a procedure from [Newsmart wiki](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/#Fix_the_MBR_in_Windows_10). The procedure is:

Boot from recovery USB | Repair your computer | Troubleshoot | Command Prompt.

```
diskpart sel disk 0 list vol
  sel vol 2
  assign letter=x:
  exit
cd /d x:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
bootrec /fixboot
ren BCD BCD.backup
bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s x: /f ALL
exit
```

Restart.

---

> Could you also post the output of list part after selecting your system disk, to make it more clear which volumes are on which disk?

```
DISKPART> list part
  Partition ###  Type      Size     Offset
  -------------  --------  -------  ---------
  Partition 1    Recovery   300 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    System     512 MB   301 MB
  Partition 3    Reserved   128 MB   813 MB
  Partition 4    Primary    893 GB   914 MB
```

> Is your laptop configured for UEFI or traditional BIOS (CSM) boot method?

My knowledge on this is rather dated and I'm not familiar with what's changed in the migration to UEFI. The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad T470s. The configuration under Startup is:

```
UEFI/Legacy Boot
 - UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority    [UEFI First]
 - CSM Support                  [Yes]
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is related to 'fixing the MBR' (and how the MBR is damaged in the first place)? What other steps are supposed to follow the ones you show?

Comment: I've added a link to the procedure I'm using and distilled the procedure into the list of commands recommended. The laptop battery was running low so I closed the lid and inserted the power supply lead. When I reopened the laptop I had the teal screen of death with error 0xc0000185 (registry) with occasional 0xc0000085 (I think) (MBR) errors on subsequent reboot. Thanks.

Comment: Is your laptop configured for UEFI or traditional BIOS (CSM) boot method? The full instructions talk about UEFI, which boots differently and does not even have a concept of a MBR (although the Windows repair commands are fairly similar in both cases). Could you also post the output of `list part` after selecting your system disk, to make it more clear which volumes are on which disk?

Comment: See the update at the end of the question. Thank you again.